# DB Design - Display forms according category

Tags: mysql, vue.js, laravel-5, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm creating a small ecommerce site and I'm concerned about form design.
My problem:
The forms depend on a chosen category , for example if the user chooses the electronic category, we will have a form of this type

- Title
- The description
- RAM
- Color

And if he chooses, for example, clothing category, we will have:

- Title
- The description
- Cut
- Color
- Feature 1
  etcc ...

My first problem is: **how can I design my mysql database to respond to this type of operation?** Should I use the Vuejs framework to create theses forms or just laravel

Does anyone have to deal with this kind of problem?
If you do not understand please leave a comment, I will try to explain myself more